# How to get db data back via repository service with MVC and Moq

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, mocking, integration-testing

I need to retrieve data from the db, via a service, in order to test captured data for structural validity.
i.e. The db data specifies the sizes of parts of a captured concatenated string, (in a certain order), which I mock.  So no worries there.
But I don't want to mock the service's data.
I want to actually retrieve the db data, which can change/vary vastly for different clients, and different scenarios, or be changed regularly.
 So, changing the mocked data for each scenario is not feasible.

The Service implements an interface and also injects the Data Access Layer's interface.

I do set 'CallBase' as true, but I'm not getting db Data back.
Please help.
Thanks

```
public interface I_PartDao
{
    ExBool List(out List<GXL_PartSizes> _PartSizes);
}

public class GXL_PartSizes
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public int? PartLength { get; set; }
        public int? SortOrder { get; set; }

        public  GXL_PartSizes()
        {
            this.ID = null;
            this.PartLength = null;
            this.SortOrder = null;
        }
    }


// Service Layer
public interface I_PartBo
{
    ExBool List(out List<GXL_PartSizes> _PartSizes);
}

public class PartBo : I_PartBo
{
    // For the injection of the Dao services (Dao handles the Ado CRUD operations against MSSQL dbase)
    private I_PartDao PartDao;

    public PartBo(I_PartDao dao_Part)
    {
        this.PartDao = dao_Part ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("dao_Part");
    }

    public ExBool List(out List<GXL_PartSizes> _PartSizes)
    {
        return this.PartDao.List(out _PartSizes);
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class GXL_ConcatenatedStructures_Test
{
    ExBool result = new ExBool();   // A class to handle error messages and statuses
    private List<GXL_PartSizes> partSizes;


    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Part_1_Length_matches_dbStructure_for_part1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockService = new Mock<I_PartBo>();

        // This is retrieved from the data posted back to the controller,..but for here and now, just a local populated strign var
        var concatenatedString_part1 = "ABC";

        // Act
        //mockService.CallBase = true;

        mockService
            .Setup(x => x.List(out partSizes))
            .Returns(result);


        //  Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(concatenatedString_part1, partSizes[0].PartLength);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that there was a way to do what I wanted to, by using moq.

However,
by just using the normal concrete classes, as per the usual (sans DI) way, The db data is retrieved.
i.e.

```
NamespaceX.GLX_SetupDao dao = new NamespaceX.GLXSetupDao("data source=LAPTOP-a; Initial 
                                                          Catalog=aaaa; Integrated Security=True;");
GLX_SetupBo boService = new GLX_SetupBo(dao);
result = boService.List(out List<GXL_PartSizes> sizes);
```